# Issue genexus cloud deploy sd for windows 8, app open and minimize after splash screen

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

Genexus developers, I'm experiencing issues after launching the app, start the splash screen, then freeze and minimize immediately. Anyone who experienced this issue?

I've started to deploy to cloud a windows 8 app using genexus ev3 update 2, working on win8.1 SO.
For quick test of win8 generator I've followed the gx wiki tutorial [My First Windows 8 App](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?My+First+Windows+8+Application,).
Tried the common solutions (registry and folder permissions, screen resolution, ...) and [Wiki GX win8 common issues](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Windows+8+-+FAQ+and+Common+Issues,) related with this with no success, everything looks as it should be.

**Solved**
Updated Genexus to Ev3 Upgrade 3 Preview 1

Comment: Have you posted the question at the Genexus's WinPhone & Windows forum? https://groups.google.com/a/genexus.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/winrt

Answer (score 1):

You should check the log to get more info.

Please see "Windows 8 Application closes unexpectedly" section at [Common issues page](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?22215)

> When the application is run (F5) a debug file is generated. Check it
>   for further info about the problem behind the app closure. File
>   location is shown at GeneXus output window (e.g. "Dashboard log file
>   will be generated at:
>   'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\Dashboard_6f78njyw3rst2\LocalState'")

If you have Visual Studio installed you can run the project there for debugging.

Comment: I've tried the common issues page before. The debug file is empty. I've tried the visual studio, the app opens and run but is not working properly, give me access level errors navigating through items.

Comment: Do you mean like Genexus Access Manager (GAM) access level errors or WinRT? Can you share any error messages you're seeing? A screenshot is also always helpful